# Use %dopar% for nested for loops to find smallest distance in R

Tags: r, optimization, foreach, doparallel

I'm currently try to match all the zip codes in the US with some zip codes I have, by the smallest distance. The code currently like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Haversine_Zip_Match)){
  # Reset the  nearest distance by every row 
  BestDist <- Inf
  for (j in 1:nrow(merged)){
    # Calculate distance 
    currDist <- dist(merged$LAT[j], Haversine_Zip_Match$LAT[i], merged$LONG[j], Haversine_Zip_Match$LONG[i])
    
    # There are some NA values for long/lat, 
    if (is.na(currDist)){
      currDist <- Inf
    }
    
    # Update best matching result
    if (currDist < BestDist){
      BestDist = currDist
      Haversine_Zip_Match$haversineMatch[i] = merged$ZIP_CD[j]
    }
  }
}
```

dist is the function I defined to calculate the distance. But "Haversine_Zip_Match" has 40,000 rows and "Merged" has 30,000 rows. In total there are over 1 billion calculations. Is there a way to make it faster? I'm currently thinking use %dopar% to expedite the process. Any idea would help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to parallelize, you could try to reduce the number of calculations.
Usually, zipcode databases define the min/max latitude and longitude around a zip code.
If you don't have this information, you can define a box around each zip code, large enough so that zipcodes box areas overlap.
In the example below, I used [this](https://github.com/cran/zipcode/blob/master/data/zipcode.rda) zipcode .rda with 43689 codes.

```
library(data.table)
library(geosphere)
points <- setDT(zipcode)[,.(zip,latitude,longitude)][!is.na(latitude)&!is.na(longitude)]
zipDB <- setDT(zipcode)[,.(zip,latitude,longitude,latmin, latmax,lonmin,lonmax)][!is.na(latitude)&!is.na(longitude)]

# full cross product :
nrow(points) * nrow(zipDB)
#[1] 1908728721

# Area limited cross product
cross <- zipDB[points,.(i.zip,i.latitude,i.longitude,zip,latitude,longitude),on = .(latmin <= latitude,lonmin <= longitude,latmax>=latitude,lonmax>=longitude)]
nrow(cross)
#[1] 18501135

# Find zip codes nearest to a point
cross[,.(i.zip, zip, dist = distHaversine(cbind(i.longitude,i.latitude),cbind(longitude,latitude)))][dist==min(dist),.(dist),by=.(i.zip,zip)]
```

As we compared the zip codes database to itself, we could expect to get exactly the same number of points, but this is not the case because some zip codes, for example 00210, 00211, ... have the same coordinates, so we get all the combinations of them.

This takes ~20s on my tablet.

Comment: @joyjoyhappyjoy, did the proposed solution work on your dataset?